# Creating JP2 with gdal in python

Tags: python, gdal, jpeg-2000

I'm using jp2 with no problem for reading and can create a copy with createcopy, but when I try to create jp2, it fails.

```
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("JP2OpenJPEG")
dst_ds = driver.Create("test.jp2",xsize=img.RasterXSize, ysize=img.RasterYSize,bands=1,eType=gdal.GDT_UInt16)
```

Same code but using GTiff driver works ok:

```
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
dst_ds = driver.Create("test.jp2",xsize=img.RasterXSize, ysize=img.RasterYSize,bands=1,eType=gdal.GDT_UInt16)
```

In the first case dst_ds is none, in the second one I get a correctly created dataset.

Note: img is another JP2 file opened without problem for reading.

Originally I was doing a createcopy, update some pixel values, doing a  WriteArray, and flushing but I can see the changes reflected in de destination file, so I decide to create from scratch.

Is there a write limitation in the driver? I'm doing something wrong?

UPDATE 1:

adding the code:

```
if(dst_ds is None):
   print(gdal.GetLastErrorMsg())
```

I'm getting the message:
GDALDriver::Create() ... no create method implemented for this format.

It does not look good....

Comment: JP2 only supports CreateCopy. Use a format like geotiff to create your raster from scratch, then write out to JP2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check what operations some format supports with gdalinfo

```
gdalinfo --format JP2OopenJPEG
Format Details:
  Short Name: JP2OpenJPEG
  Long Name: JPEG-2000 driver based on OpenJPEG library
  Supports: Raster
  Supports: Vector
  Extensions: jp2 j2k
  Mime Type: image/jp2
  Help Topic: frmt_jp2openjpeg.html
  Supports: Open() - Open existing dataset.
  Supports: CreateCopy() - Create dataset by copying another.
  Supports: Virtual IO - eg. /vsimem/
  Creation Datatypes: Byte Int16 UInt16 Int32 UInt32
```

So no support for Create() in JP2OpenJPEG as you have noticed. I believe that JPEG2000 belongs to those "sequential write once formats" which are mentioned in http://www.gdal.org/classGDALDriver.html.

> Note that many sequential write once formats (such as JPEG and PNG)
>   don't implement the Create() method but do implement this CreateCopy()
>   method. If the driver doesn't implement CreateCopy(), but does
>   implement Create() then the default CreateCopy() mechanism built on
>   calling Create() will be used. So to test if CreateCopy() is
>   available, you can test if GDAL_DCAP_CREATECOPY or GDAL_DCAP_CREATE is
>   set in the GDAL metadata.
>
> It is intended that CreateCopy() will often be used with a source
>   dataset which is a virtual dataset allowing configuration of band
>   types, and other information without actually duplicating raster data
>   (see the VRT driver). This is what is done by the gdal_translate
>   utility for example.